# How to handle difference responses API?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to handle the difference between the results of a successful and failed fire response?

RESPONSE SUCCESS:

```
{
   "header":{
      "status":true,
      "respcode":"00",
      "message":"Successfully."
   },
   "data":{
      "userid":"3485345",
      "password":"3423424",
      "bit18":"0000",

   }
}
```

RESPONSE FAILED:

```
{
   "header":{
      "status":false,
      "respcode":"01",
      "message":"Userid Tidak Terdaftar"
   },
   "data":""
}
```

Comment: How are you currently handling this JSON, kindly post the code.

Comment: model : https://pastebin.com/cGr1JYvd
api base helper : https://pastebin.com/tGLe8Bf5
repository : https://pastebin.com/KeZ9WbjY
bloc : https://pastebin.com/w0iXYY5a
ui : https://pastebin.com/2qfFNycp

Comment: hope you can help me

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why in the failed case, data is string (and not object). In theory, the failed case should have an empty object instead of a string. Any way, assuming you don't have control over the server's response, you might want to do something like below :

(The first two lines I wrote just to make sure the parsing works.)

```
Map<String, dynamic> mData = {
                              "header":{
                                  "status":true,
                                  "respcode":"00",
                                  "message":"Successfully."
                              },
                              "data":{
                                  "userid":"3485345",
                                  "password":"3423424",
                                  "bit18":"0000",

                              }
                            };

    String jData = json.encode(mData);

    Map<String, dynamic> decodedBody = json.decode(jData);

    print(decodedBody["header"]["respcode"]);  // prints 00

    if (decodedBody['header']['status'])
    {
      User user = User.fromJson(decodedBody['data']);
      print(user.userId);  // This prints 3485345
    }
    else {
       // login failed
    }
```

And the User model is defined as below :

```
class User {
  final String userId;
  final String password;
  final String bit18;

  User({@required this.userId, @required this.password, this.bit18});

  User.fromJson(Map json)
      : this.userId = json['userid'],
        this.password = json['password'],
        this.bit18 = json['bit18'];
}
```

Comment: actually I know, I have to create an empty object like this right:
'{
   "header":{
      "status":true,
      "respcode":"00",
      "message":"Successfully."
   },
   "data":{
      "userid":"",
      "password":"",
      "bit18":"",

   }
}'

but if there are so many objects I have to make the object empty too, in my opinion it is very tiring. but if it has to be that way, then I have to follow it

Comment: Having the same structure is good from the server-side as well. However, as I said, if it is not possible for any reason (including efforts not worth spending), you can do with the limited parsing as I demonstrated. Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

assuming you'll always have headers in your responses, you can do something like this:

```
Map<String, dynamic> res1 = {
    "header": {"status": true, "respcode": "00", "message": "Successfully."},
    "data": {
      "userid": "3485345",
      "password": "3423424",
      "bit18": "0000",
    }
  };

  Map<String, dynamic> res2 = {
    "header": {
      "status": false,
      "respcode": "01",
      "message": "Userid Tidak Terdaftar"
    },
    "data": ""
  };

  // bla = res2 for failed case
  final bla = res1;
  if (bla['header']['status']) {
    print(res1['data']['userid']);
    // do your success code here
  } else {
   // do your fail code here
    print('fail');
  }
```